# Update checkbox data in SQL-database with PHP

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

As the title reveals I got an issue with how to update a checkbox that already has data in my SQL database.

My code looks like following:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Name <input type"text" name="inputName" value="<?php echo $hemsida['Namn']; ?>" /> </br>
Commentar <input type"text" name="inputComment" value="<?php echo $hemsida['Comment']; ?>" />
<br/>
</br><input type="checkbox" name="inputAll" value="checked" <?php echo $hemsida['All']; ?>/>Alla
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Redigera">
```

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $u = "UPDATE hemsida SET `Namn`='$_POST[inputName]', `Comment`='$_POST[inputComment]', `ALL`='$_POST[inputALL]' WHERE ID = $_POST[id]";
    mysql_query($u) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "User has been modified";
    header("Location: ..//sokh.php");
} 
?>
```

The echo $hemsida['Namn'],['Comment'], and ['All'] just brings up and shows the old data thats in the database, but I do not understand what to do to update the checkbox. I have looked everywhere but I am stuck. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Part of the code disappeared, the issue is in the second PHP part (that just came back) that picks up the Form. I can see how it still is an unclear question. This is my first question in my life in Stack Overflow. The ALL='$_POST[inputALL]' is the thing that do not pick up any data at all. Do not know how to make it work. Thank you for the quick response though! The value of <?php echo $hemsida['All']; ?> is "checked" so everything works when it get in to the "Modifier" or what i should call it. The problem is getting it back.

Comment: i update my answer look if this is what do you want

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but i think you have a column in your database named "all" ? and perhaps this column can take only 1 value (true or false) !!

then you can test this value in your form, if the value is true : checkbox will be checked, else : checkbox will not be checked :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inputAll" checked="<?php if($hemsida['All'] == true) echo checked; ?>" />Alla
```

dont use value="", use checked instead, then test value of $hemsida['All'] if it's true echo checked else anything to do

for your php code and server side of your application you can just test if checkbox is checked and then you have choice for what do you want to assign to your column in database, for example if checkbox is checked create a variable (for example $value_of_checkbox) and assign a value ("true" for exampel) to this variable,  then include this variable in your sql code for update database column :

```
    if (isset($_POST['inputALL'])) {
       $value_of_checkbox = true;
    }
    else {
       $value_of_checkbox = false;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $u = "UPDATE hemsida SET `Namn`='$_POST[inputName]', `Comment`='$_POST[inputComment]', `ALL`='$value_of_checkbox' WHERE ID = $_POST[id]";

    mysql_query($u) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "User has been modified";
    header("Location: ..//sokh.php")
```

**note** : i change also sql code in this part : `ALL='$value_of_checkbox'`

Comment: Part of the code disappeared, the issue is in the second PHP part (that just came back) that picks up the Form. I can see how it still is an unclear question. This is my first question in my life in Stack Overflow. The ALL='$_POST[inputALL]' is the thing that do not pick up any data at all. Do not know how to make it work. Thank you for the quick response though! The value of <?php echo $hemsida['All']; ?> is "checked" so everything works when it get in to the "Modifier" or what i should call it. The problem is getting it back.

Comment: you have on your database table a column called "ALL" i'm right ? and you have a checkbox called inputAll right?  when you send your form this checkbox if is checked --> $_POST['inputALL'] exist, if not checked ---> $_POST['inputALL'] dont exist, i tell you to verify that with if (isset($_POST['inputALL'])) this means if your checkbox is checked, then i create a variable and assign true to it, else i assign false, finally i pass this variable to sql code : ALL = $variable instead of ALL="$_POST[inputALL]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a way to have a checkbox be either checked or not checked depending on database info. If so, I would try something like this. At the top of your code where you get your database info, put

```
if($conditionForCheck){
   $inputAll = ' checked="checked"';
}
```

Then in your form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inputAll"<?php echo $inputAll; ?> />
```

Comment: Part of the code disappeared, the issue is in the second PHP part (that just came back) that picks up the Form. I can see how it still is an unclear question. This is my first question in my life in Stack Overflow. The `ALL`='$_POST[inputALL]' is the thing that do not pick up any data at all. Do not know how to make it work. Thank you for the quick response though! The value of <?php echo $hemsida['All']; ?> is "checked" so everything works when it get in to the "Modifier" or what i should call it. The problem is getting it back.